# Proper punctuation for "and what's more"?

Tags: phrases

I have seen this phrasing as

> And what's more -
>
> And what's more,
>
> And what's more!

Which one is most proper?

Comment: He gave me some s'more. And what s'more! The most delicious I have ere now had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you have something to follow:

- And, what's more, he also did that!

With the following text, it is clear that an exclamation mark after the phrase is inappropriate.  The dash is not appropriate either - it is used to mark a break of some sort, but the text that follows "what is more" or its contraction "what's more" is a continuation of the previous thinking, not a contrasting thought.

A comma is fine; what's more, it is the punctuation I'd use automatically.

Whether the comma is necessary, or allowable, after the "and" is perhaps a little debatable.  As you can see, I'd use it; and, what's more, it feels right because there is a small parenthetical break around the "what's more" part of the phrase.